# RMarkdown bibliography references in a ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, cross-reference

I would like to create a ggplot with articles references on one axis. I was wondering if it is possible to put the conventional Rmarkdown citation syntax as a variable input (*e.g.* `@barnagaud_temporal_2017`) and to see the clean reference in the plot (*i.e.* `Barnagaud et al. (2017)`)

Here is an example: my column contains the reference under Rmarkdown syntax. I would like the correct syntax instead.

[image]

Comment: You want to see it both in html and pdf?

Comment: I don' t think this can be done easily as I don't know of a way to get those formatted reference names outside of building the document.

Comment: @RichardJ.Acton But it is an interesting question, cool to see an answer.

Comment: could you give a complete example with the actual ref and the markdown file? I think you should have a look to ggtext, which allow markdown text in ggplot (like in title or axis)

Comment: @manro - that's where it is tricky: I don't want to knit it, just to produce the plot

Comment: Interesting @denis, I'll edit my question soon

Comment: @FrsLry ... produce the plot in viewer?

Comment: @manro yes, exactly